# Prevent Browser History from Firing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I want to have an alert box show up before a user leaves a certain url

```
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const routeChangeListener = browserHistory.listenBefore(location => {
      console.log(location);
      routeChangeListener();
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave the page without saving?';
    });
  }
```

This works, but the problem is

1. The alert box is still firing after I leave the route.
2. If I say no, I don't want to cancel from the alert box, it doesn't fire again if I try to leave the route.

I can't cancel the firing of the route when I leave and I can't initiate the dialog box if I say I want to cancel the dialog and I think it might be because I call routeChangeListener after componentWillMount. I eventually want to fire a modal window in here instead of using this alert box.

What am I missing to cancel/prevent routeChangeListener after the dialog is fired?

Comment: Where is the alert box in your code? I don't see it listed

Comment: @winhowes return 'Are you sure you want to leave the page without saving?'; fires a windows alert dialog

Comment: If you have the alert in there instead does that give you the result you're looking for?

Comment: @winhowes I'm planning to add my own modal but as of now the current code does not work properly so I'm planning to add that after it works. Hope that makes sense